# Capturing web page data to an email

Tags: email

Is it possible to create Greasemonkey script or something to grab text from a web site and autofill an Outlook 2007 email with that data?

I often need to send a standardized email to clients.  The client's email address, username and temporary password are the only thing that changes between emails sent.  It would be nice If I could have a script to grab specific fields from the client account page and auto populate that into an email so all I have to do is review it and send.

Thank in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think Greasemonkey can bend security a little, so if you set the browser's URL to a `mailto:` URL, the email client will open.

You can also fill in the body and subject fields:

```
mailto:your@email.com?subject=Hullo&body=First Paragraph. %0A%0A Second paragraph. %0A%0A Third Paragraph etc.
```